# I cannot connect to a particular SQL Server 2008 database server from C#

Tags: c#

I cannot connect to a particular SQL Server 2008 database server from C#.
My Sharp code cannot connect to the database. Connection works. I do not 
know what the problem is. error when compiling code in the photo.Error with sqlclient. I don't really understand the sql requests. enter code here`Error with  con.Open(); all data is correct but the error is still in progress

```
string conStr = "Data Source=10.21.168.30,1433;Initial 
Catalog=СС_Vesy_1_19_03_12_14_22_18R;Persist Security Info=True;User 
ID=mic;Password=mic";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        con.Open();
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfpMN.png]

Comment: Ух как на симпотяшку наехали :D

Comment: Make sure that username and password are correct and that the database server indeed contains the database `СС_Vesy_1_19_03_12_14_22_18R` for which the user (`mic` in your case) has access.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial C# code looks fine. (I would put the entire connection string on a single line, however, if you did not do so in your original code.)

The error message implies, that the server does not know user "mic", or that the password "mic" is invalid for that user. Perhaps you need to create a SQL user named "mic" and with password "mac" on your server using SQL Server Management Studio first.

And you also need to make sure that user "mic" has access to database "СС_Vesy_1_19_03_12_14_22_18R".

If you can connect to your database using SQL Server Management Studio with user "mic" and password "mic", your C# connection string should work fine too...

Edit:

I tested it shortly on my local computer.

First I created a database called "Test" and a login called "mac". ;) I fetched those actions in the following SQL script:

```
USE [master]
GO

IF DB_ID('Test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP DATABASE [Test];
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[syslogins] WHERE [loginname] = 'mac')
    DROP LOGIN [mac];
GO

CREATE DATABASE [Test];
CREATE LOGIN [mac] WITH PASSWORD=N'mac', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO

USE [Test]
GO

CREATE USER [mac] FOR LOGIN [mac];
GO

ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [mac];
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [mac];
GO
```

Then I created a console application in Visual Studio with the following code in Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string conStr = "Data Source=10.21.168.30,1433;Initial Catalog=СС_Vesy_1_19_03_12_14_22_18R;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mic;Password=mic";
        string conStr = "Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mac;Password=mac";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@VERSION", con);

        con.Open();
        string version = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        Console.WriteLine(version);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And this works for me. The SQL Server version information is displayed in a console window.

I only had to change the connection string so that my console application connects to my Test database. And I used an additional SqlCommand object to execute a SQL query to retrieve the SQL Server version using the established connection.

By the way, I would also use using-blocks to dispose the connection and the command objects when they are not needed anymore. So my actual final C# code would look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string conStr = "Data Source=10.21.168.30,1433;Initial Catalog=СС_Vesy_1_19_03_12_14_22_18R;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mic;Password=mic";
        string conStr = "Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mac;Password=mac";
        string version;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@VERSION", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            version = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(version);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the SQL Server Management Studio, the user “mac” has access to the database CC_Vesy_1_19_03_12_14_22_18R I think my code is a little wrong.

Comment: That's strange. As far as I can see, the code looks fine and you are creating a SQL Server connection correctly. I myself have been using code like that for years without any problems. But I will check it again. (By the way, sorry that I called your user "mac" instead of "mic". I meant "mic", of course, and I updated my answer.)

Comment: Jep. Works fine with me. I will update my answer to show you how I tested it completely.